# How to get Text box value from Grid view header template?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want grid view header template textbox value. I write code for getting value but it return null.

```
<asp:Button ID="btngetLocationDate" runat="server" Text="Get Filtered Data" OnClick="getTextBoxValue"></asp:Button>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile Number">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                      Mobile Number:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobilenumber" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mobile Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And On the code behind.cs i write that code but it returns null

```
  protected void getTextBoxValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //TableCell cell1 = TrackerGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0];

        TextBox mobilenumber = (TrackerGrid.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtMobilenumber") as TextBox) ;
        string mobile = mobilenumber.Text;
```

How can I resolve this ? please help me!

Comment: Where in code-behind do you wrote that code?

Comment: This code works, if the GridView has any rows in them. If there are no rows the textbox does not exist.

Comment: I updated my code with code behind code

Comment: Hello VDWWD, the textbox on gridview heder and I am using for filtering the gridview data.

Answer (score -1):

I've just had a similar problem by trying to get textbox text from the footer row. I'm not sure if this is the best way to get around this problem but this should work if FindControl() successfully assigns the textbox.

```
TextBox mobilenumber = (TrackerGrid.HeaderRow.FindControl("txtMobilenumber") as TextBox);
string mobile = Request.Form[mobilenumber.UniqueID];
```

EDIT: As VDWWD commented, Request.Form is a bad practice.  But for my particular usage I couldn't find any other way to get the data from a textbox on button click due to my unorganized postbacks.

Comment: Using `Request.Form` is bad practice and should not be needed.

Comment: Apart from the big collection size on certain pages, what are the other downsides of using Request.Form ?